# How do I make my react app still run with lint errors?

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, visual-studio-code

I am working on a React application with webpack, when I run 'npm start' it takes a long time to build, but if there are lint errors it will fail at the end of the build with 'Exit status 1' and I will need to fix the error and then run 'npm start'.

The errors are things like 'un-used var', 'line too long' etc. so they shouldn't stop the app from running, and it wastes my time to wait for it to build again.

I still want to see the lint errors, but how can I stop them from causing the build to Exit?

Comment: What does `npm start` do? Is this create-react-app?

Comment: lint errors are not fatal, something else is causing it to fail.

Answer (score 2):

If the lint error/warning causes the exit, you may want to update your eslint loader configuration according to this https://github.com/webpack-contrib/eslint-loader#errors-and-warning

A simple instruction:

1.Go to your Webpack configuration file.

Find a loader called 'eslint-loader', you may exepect something like this:

```
rules: [
  {
    test: /\.js$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    loader: "eslint-loader",
    options: {
    /* this is the eslint-loader option */
      failOnWarning: true
    }
  }
]
```

2.In the `options` filed under the eslint-loader. you may want to update this field to something like:

```
rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: "eslint-loader",
        options: {
        /* this is the eslint-loader option */
          failOnWarning: false,
          failOnError: false
        }
      }
    ]
```

In this case, though your eslint-loader find error/warnings. The building won't crash. (though this is not recommended)

Answer (score 1):

I am working with Create-React-App and had this issue. I had to manually install eslint-webpack-plugin. Link: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/eslint-webpack-plugin

And then, in node modules, react scripts, config, webpack.config.js file, I looked for the ESLintPlugin, and added as an option:

> failOnError: false

. Please take a look at the screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

I found several solutions at https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/7933 such as

```
npm run lint -s
```

or

```
eslint .; exit 0
```